# Use multiline PHP variable as argument for executing bash script

Tags: php, bash

In PHP, I have a variable that returns a multi-line text, similar to what is displayed below.

```
*
*clefF4
*k[f#c#g#d#a#]
*d:
*M6/4
```

I then want to use this variable in PHP as an argument to execute a bash script.
My PHP code for doing so is below (Where `$filechosen` is the string of text above):

```
$output = shell_exec("/path/to/bash/script.sh $filechosen");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Below is that extremely simple bash script that uses the variable '`$filechosen`' as an argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

returnExpression=$(echo "$1" | grep 'k\[')
echo $returnExpression
```

However, when I run this, I get no output. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always escape variables that you're substituting into command lines, and PHP provides a function `escapeshellarg()` to do it.

```
$output = shell_exec("/path/to/bash/script.sh " . escapeshellarg($filechosen));
```

or

```
$escaped = escapeshellarg($filechosen);
$output = shell_exec("/path/to/bash/script.sh $escaped");
```

Comment: With slight modification, this worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: What was the modification?

Comment: For some reason, the syntax in the answer wasn't working, so I set a separate variable, filechoose: `$filechose = escapeshellarg($filechosen);`
Then the execution of the script was changed to this:
`$output = shell_exec("/path/to/bash/script.sh $filechose");`

Comment: There really shouldn't be any difference between concatenating variables and substituting into the string. Did you remember to leave a space after `.sh` when you concatenated?

Comment: I did. For some reason, it still isn't working with concatenation.

Comment: I don't believe you, you must have done something wrong.

Comment: I apologize, both are correct!
(I'm somewhat new to PHP)

Comment: No problem. I'm always willing to be caught in an error here (I make typos sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

In GNU/Linux the common way of commands is to process streams. Also `grep` does so. Whenever possible, you should not break this pattern. In your paricular example it does not make sense to wrap it into positional parameters.

You can use `popen` to write a stream to the executed command:

```
<pre>
<?php

$filechosen = <<<_EOS_
*
*clefF4
*k[f#c#g#d#a#]
*d:
*M6/4
_EOS_;


if($handle = popen("grep 'k\\['", "w"))
{
  fwrite($handle, $filechosen);
  pclose($handle);
}

?>
<pre>
```

Use `proc_open` function instead when you want to read the output stream into a variable.

```
if($handle = proc_open("grep 'k\\['", [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']], $streams))
{
  [$stdin, $stdout, $stderr] = $streams;

  fwrite($stdin, $filechosen);
  fclose($stdin);

  $output = stream_get_contents($stdout);
  fclose($stdout);

  $error  = stream_get_contents($stderr);
  fclose($stderr);

  proc_close($handle);
  echo $output;
}
```